# Boujou to blender, how to fix camera and dots

Tags: python

Hi Blender wizards out there!
I am having a problem with my motion tracked data from boujou to blender. I know how to export from boujou and in to blender, but when the camera appears, first thing I notice is, that all of the "dots" from boujou isn't imported from boujou. The second problem is the camera is upside down. In 3DS MAX you can rotate your whole scene, this option seems to be missing in blender?
Is there a way to rotate the whole scene without interrupting the animations of the camera?

[image: Camera upside down]

Please help..

Comment: Would look into how you import the camera track. Blender uses Z axis up Y axis forward.  The camera looks down it's -Z axis. Would make these changes in the importer to convert from ... is 3ds Y up Z forward to blender.

Comment: True, I'll take a look at that. I was just watching this tutorial: https://youtu.be/OntNstHgkZY?t=16m28s where he talks about it as being a software issue in general. So it needs to be fixed in the 3D program.

Comment: "Just rotate the scene 190 degrees on the first frame, rearrange the scene, and everything should be fine." - how on earth do you do that  xD

Comment: One way to rearrange scene. Put an empty at origin, make it a parent to all parentless objects and rotate / scale  accordingly.  To apply, select empty apply rot / scale and then remove.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this. Maybe I'll need you to show me what you mean. Anyways, went through some old Boujou to blender tutorials on youtube, and apparently it used to import both all the dots and the camera right into blender. Do you know if Blender actually changed something?